# set target audience list item

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, audience-targeting

I have a list with 12 items and 6 groups. Now I want each group can view two of items.

Can I set target audience and enable it on each list item?

Answer (score 0):

Option one - Create unique permission on each item

Option two - Create separate views for each group. Then create a page and add those views as list view webparts. And apply audience targeting on those webparts.